# Cannot connect to an application running on an oracle cloud vm

Tags: virtual-machine, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have an oracle Ubuntu virtual machine running a game server for a game I am working on. I also have clients that I want to connect to this server, I am using a C# networking library called Riptide Networking that I believe uses a mixture of both. However when I go to connect to the server using the virtual machines public ip address all I am getting back is a 'failed to connect' message.  I have checked that the Security List rules allow all TCP and UDP connections both inbound and outbound on all ports and from all addresses. Does anyone know any reason why I would not be able to connect to the server?

I have tried looking at the rout table and everything there seems fine. I have also tried explicitly allowing connections on the port that I am using still nothing. I can still connect to the vm via ssh. I have also tried using the command line 'telnet' command and it also cannot connect to the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the answer was port forwarding, all I needed to do was run a command like this:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 63231 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 63231 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 63231 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 63231 -j ACCEPT
```

And connections to the port 63231 were allowed